# Fazer intervalo de datas datepicker ser usada no mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, bootstrap, data, datepicker

No meu código, tenho um calendário onde o usuário seleciona o período que ele deseja analisar. O código é este:

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2012 - 20/04/2018" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: false,
    timePickerIncrement: 0,
    locale: {
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Preciso usar esse intervalo para filtrar uma tabela de dados mysql. Já usei a função `between`com duas datas distintas, dessa forma:

```
SELECT * FROM `producao_hora` where data between '19/04/2018' and '20/04/2018'
```

Mas não sei como transformar o intervalo de datas do datepicker numa variável que eu pudesse jogar nesse `select`. Como poderia ser feito?
OBS: Códigos em PHP também são bem-vindos!

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite Renata,

Como você esta trabalhando com PHP. Você pode simplesmente realizar o submit do formulário. E no script que receber a requisição dividir a string para obter as duas datas. E posteriormente montar sua query.

**formulario.html:**

```
<form action="pesquisar.php" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2012 - 20/04/2018" />
            <button type="submit">Filtrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
            timePicker: false,
            timePickerIncrement: 0,
            locale: {
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**pesquisar.php:**

```
<?php
    $datas = explode(' - ', $_POST['daterange']);
    echo $datas[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $datas[1];
```

Veja que utilizei a função explode para separar as datas do intervalo. Portanto a nova variável terá na primeira posição a data inicial do intervalo e na segunda posição o fim do intervalo.